# How to show particular 'dot' or hidden files on OS X

Tags: macos, git

**Is there a way to configure OSX to always show particular dot files?**

I'm familiar with the commands to toggle between showing and hiding hidden files.

**Show Hidden Files:**

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 1 && killall Finder
```

**Hide Hidden Files:**

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 0 && killall Finder
```

I also created a quick-click macro to toggle visibility using these commands; however, even this usage is annoying because of frequency. The reason I toggle often is because I prefer not to have all hidden files always visible.   Hiding minimizes chance of accidental selections, deletions, etc.

For example, in many of my projects I want to always see `.jshintrc` and `.gitignore` files but, do not want `.git` folders to also be visible.

Comment: At first I thought that `setFile -a V` could be used, in conjunction with your `defaults write` command, but the `defaults` setting seems to override what setFile does.  Best recommendation I can think of is do like `ln -s .gitignore "!gitignore"` (with hidden files be turned off).  You'll see "!gitignore" at the top of your Finder window (if sorting by name), so it will be in a similar place to where ".gitignore" would have been, but it will be visible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to show only some hidden files unless you do as jimtut said and create a link to a file. You can also use Terminal to show the file listing with `ls -a`.
 
If the file doesn't need to be hidden with a '.' you can toggle it's visibility with the `chflags nohidden fileName` command, but this doesn't change visibility for files beginning with a '.'.

Comment: I knew there was another command to change visibility of a single file, but I couldn't remember `chflags`.  Looks like both `chflags` and `setFile` set the same underlying attributes.  You can check the attributes with `GetFileInfo`.  Those set/get commands do require the Apple Developer Tools or something.  Google it; it's worth it.